# Using keydown event with d3.drag () to rotate a SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a SVG and I want to apply rotation transformation on it but not just with the mouse drag, instead with a mouse drag while pressing the `alt` key. I have tried to implement something but things donot seem to work as I want. Below is what i have implemented. How can I get the SVG rotated on dragging the mouse while pressing the `alt` key?

```
var width = 590, height = 400;


var svg = d3.select("#sketch4").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    //.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed))
    .call(d3.drag().on('drag', dragged))
    .append("g")

var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("width", 60)
    .attr("height", 30)
    .attr("fill", "green")



  function dragged() {
                if (d3.event.sourceEvent.altKey){
                var me = sketchSVG.node()
                var x1 = me.getBBox().x + me.getBBox().width/2;
                var y1 = me.getBBox().y + me.getBBox().height/2;
                sketchSVG.attr("transform","rotate("+d3.event.y+","+x1+","+y1+")" );
                metricSVG.attr("transform","rotate("+d3.event.y+","+x1+","+y1+")" );
                }
            };
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If not whats the value of `d3.event.sourceEvent.altKey` while dragging.

Comment: Also this should be phrased as a question. Rather than a request for someone to fix.

Comment: I don't get any error and on dragging there is no value seen.

Comment: So your code looks fine. It's just a matter of getting the correct output in the if condition. What version of D3 are you using? What do the docs say about key binding events in that version?

Comment: I am using version 4.

Comment: I can see a few examples on the Internet of keybinding but in those examples there is just the action using keys and not the mouse drag along with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `d3.event.sourceEvent.x` and `d3.event.sourceEvent.y`. Changing that should get your code working.

To move/zoom your element, create and `else` condition and just use `sketchSVG.attr("transform",d3.event.transform)` for `zooming` and `translating` the element.

```js
var width = 590,
  height = 400;


var svg = d3.select("#sketch4").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr('id', 'sketchSvg')
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")

d3.select('#sketchSvg')
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", dragged))

var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr("width", 60)
  .attr("height", 30)
  .attr("fill", "green")



function dragged(d) {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent.altKey && d3.event.sourceEvent.type == 'mousemove') {
    var me = svg.node()
    var x1 = me.getBBox().x + me.getBBox().width / 2;
    var y1 = me.getBBox().y + me.getBBox().height / 2;
    svg.attr("transform", "rotate(" + d3.event.sourceEvent.y + "," + x1 + "," + y1 + ")");
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='sketch4'></div>
```

Here's one on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aditya_kk29/os05gjoq/)

Comment: The thing with your solution is that the SVG rotates when alt and scroll event occurs. I want it to rotate using alt and drag event. What should I do for that?

Comment: @Salman Checking if the event type is `mousemove` should do that. I have updated the fiddle